# Trying to assign/extract variables to different elements in a list of lists with prolog

Tags: prolog

I'm trying to work through this [Prolog problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GXiRl.png), however, I'm struggling to get my solution working and was wondering whether someone could help me fix the error -[example trace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T0ynE.png). Here is my code so far;

```
process(L1, [H2|T2], [H2|T], Inconsistent):-
    H2 = [Name, Number, _Info],
    elementInList(L1, [Name, Number]),
    process(L1, T2, T, Inconsistent).
process(L1, [H2|T2], Consistent, [H2|T]):-
    H2 = [Name, Number, _Info],
    \+ elementInList(L1, [Name, Number]),
    process(L1, T2, Consistent, T).
process(_L1, [], [], []).

elementInList([H|T], H).
elementInList([H|T], E):-
    elementInList(T, E).
```

EDIT: PROBLEM FIXED. Solution: [working code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WfS3Q.png)

Comment: The trace shows the problem is the unification. Change the brackets.

Comment: `H2 = (Name, Number, _Info)`

Answer (score 1):

You need to replace square brackets to paranthesis in couple of places.  Here's the complete code, which runs perfectly on swi - prolog. I have added cut and done some shuffling of statements for optimization.

```
process(_L1, [], [], []):- !.
process(L1, [H2|T2], [H2|T], Inconsistent):-
    H2 = (Name, Number, _Info),
    elementInList(L1, (Name, Number)), !,
    process(L1, T2, T, Inconsistent).
process(L1, [H2|T2], Consistent, [H2|T]):-
    H2 = (Name, Number, _Info),
    \+ elementInList(L1, (Name, Number)),
    process(L1, T2, Consistent, T).

elementInList([H|_], H):- !.
elementInList([_|T], E):-
    elementInList(T, E).
```